# Series Radius/interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: radius of convergence]

Help please! I have no idea how to do this question. I tried using the ratio test

Comment: Ratio Test does work nicely.

Comment: I got R=0 and [16,16] for the interval of convergence when I used the ratio test. I'm not sure what to do with the 4n in the denominator using the ratio test...

Comment: As explained by HK Lee, the limit of the ratio is $0$ for any $x$. So the series converges for every $x$, the radius of convergence is "infinite".

Answer (score 1):

$a_n = \frac{n^4(x-16)^n}{4\cdot 8\cdots (4n)} $ Then $$ \bigg|
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigg| =\frac{(n+1)^4}{n^4} |x-16|
\frac{1}{4(n+1)}\rightarrow 0 $$

Hence $R=\infty$ and $(-\infty ,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a power series, $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n(x-x_0)^n$, then 
$$
R=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|
$$
In this case 
$$
R=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^4 4(n+1)}{(n+1)^4}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4n^4}{(n+1)^3}=\infty
$$
So $R=\infty$ and $(-\infty, \infty)$ is the interval of convergence.